# Error 29 on mysql workbench, how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Good morning everyone, I'm starting to approach mysql and obviously the first problems are starting, I'm trying to upload a csv file that I created and initially it gave me error code 1290 which I solved by modifying the .ini file, when I hoped everything would be resolved I noticed which now, despite copying the path of the file, tells me that the file does not exist giving error number 29.
Could anyone help me?

I tried to change the .ini file and restart che server on the windows services but nothing happened.